# WebKit jagged image on resize

Tags: html, css, webkit

We're having a problem when an image (logo) is resized in WebKit, it is jagged for a couple of seconds. We've tried resizing it both by changing width in CSS and using scale transformation. Is there any way to fix this?

[image]
[image]

http://codepen.io/Znarkus/pen/xbxKLK

Example HTML:

```
<div>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LoN4Mnz.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ddd;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}


div:hover img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: This is also true for Safari and Opera on Mac. So not Chrome specific.

Comment: But not Firefox, so maybe a Webkit issue?

Comment: Changed to WebKit in question

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with the antialiasing of the images which has a short delay. My searches did not yield any good answers on how to solve this, so I've come up with two possible solutions.

**Solution 1**

Keep two versions of the image pre-rendered, then switch between the different sizes.

*Pros*: Perfect rendering

*Cons*:  Takes more memory

**Solution 2**

User the [image-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) CSS property to disable antialiasing. By adding `image-rendering: [browser specific see codepen fork];` to the div, you can see that the rendering of the image isn't as good as without antialiasing.

*Pros*: All CSS, no extra memory consumption

*Cons*: Lesser image quality

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJWrvJ

***EDIT***: **Solution 3**

On second though, there might be a different solution. Images aren't particulary great for rendering text, but since it's a logo I'm guessing you have some kind of special twist on the text or styling. If you can export the logo as svg and render it in a canvas you might be able to get around these problems.